# How do I automatically store photos from emails or texts directly to the Camera roll?

Tags: photos, messages

My son tried to explain the process to me, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone, there's no way currently that I know of to automatically save images from Messages to your Camera Roll. However, you can save images in bulk from Messages to your Camera Roll:

1. Open Messages and select the conversation with the images
2. Select **Details** in the upper right (iOS 11) *or*
   Tap on the top bar and then select the **info** icon that appears (iOS 12)
3. Lightly press and hold on one of the images you'd like to save.
4. Select **More** in the popup menu
5. Select the rest of the images you'd like to save
6. Select **Save Images** in the bottom left corner.